# Cabal cannot resolve dependencies - chooses wrong version of `containers`?

Tags: cabal

```
% cabal sandbox init
Writing a default package environment file to
/Users/pmw/yesod-website/cabal.sandbox.config
Creating a new sandbox at /Users/pmw/yesod-website/.cabal-sandbox
0c4de9cd2926% cabal install --upgrade-dependencies --constraint="template-haskell installed" --dependencies-only --enable-tests
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: yesod-website-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
trying: text-1.2.1.1 (dependency of yesod-website-0.1.0.0)
trying: binary-0.7.5.0 (dependency of text-1.2.1.1)
trying: containers-0.5.6.3 (dependency of binary-0.7.5.0)
trying: yesod-form-1.4.4.1 (dependency of yesod-website-0.1.0.0)
next goal: template-haskell (dependency of yesod-form-1.4.4.1)
rejecting: template-haskell-2.10.0.0 (global constraint requires installed
instance)
rejecting: template-haskell-2.9.0.0/installed-c0b... (conflict:
containers==0.5.6.3, template-haskell => containers==0.5.5.1/installed-d4b...)
rejecting: template-haskell-2.9.0.0, 2.8.0.0, 2.7.0.0, 2.6.0.0, 2.5.0.0,
2.4.0.1, 2.4.0.0, 2.3.0.1, 2.3.0.0, 2.2.0.0 (global constraint requires
installed instance)
Backjump limit reached (change with --max-backjumps).

Note: when using a sandbox, all packages are required to have consistent
dependencies. Try reinstalling/unregistering the offending packages or
recreating the sandbox.
```

My cabal file:

```
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable yesod-website
  main-is:             helloworld.hs
  build-depends:       yesod
                       , yesod-form
                       , text
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

When I run a plain `cabal install` instead, it succeeds.  But that's not an option for me: I am running this particular invocation of `cabal install` because I am trying to integrate with CircleCI, and that's the exact command they run.  On their system (Linux), it fails precisely the same way as on mine (OS X).

What is happening?

Comment: This looks like a typical cabal dependency solver shortcoming. Can you try running again with `--max-backjumps=-1 --reorder-goals`?

Comment: @Philip can you post an answer that documents how this was resolved, just for posterity?